# Ubuntu14.04LSM Wireless Network Configuration Through Command Line

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I installed Ubuntu few days ago, at that time i didn't have available internet connection. But the wireless network has connected and its strength is good. Except that, the network history of the system monitor shows that the receving is 0kb/s, as shown in the follow image.

So i want to know how to solve the problem and hope someone can have a good solution for me. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you'd probably get better support [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/)

However, you are receiving as it says you've received 24.6MB according to the system monitor.

if you can `ping -c 3 example.com` you will see if you are connecting properly or not.

Comment: ok, thanks. I have input the command into the terminal. The result shows that the connecting is ok. And i want to know how to speed up my network. I have found that modifying the DNS is the key solution. But I have no idea about it.